# What timestamp format is "xTxx:xx:xx"?

Tags: date, time, timestamp, format, hour

I have come across a certain attribute that returns timestamp values in a format like - "xTxx:xx:xx". What does the first 'x' signify?

My first guess was that the first 'x' stands for days but I'm not sure if that's right or not.

Comment: Without some sample values it can be anything.

Comment: The presence of the `T` strongly suggests [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or at least a format derived or inspired from ISO 8601. In ISO 8601 if there is something before the `T`, it’s a date in 7 or 8 digits and/or separated by hyphens. Two examples: (1) `2022-11-13T12:34:56` (2) `2022-318T12:34:56` (the 318th day of 2022). If there is only one digit before `T`, it isn’t ISO 8601. If that digit is in the 1 - 7 range, could it then be a day of week?